# Dart Client-Side Type Generic REST Api Calls

Tags: flutter, rest, http, dart

It is my understanding that one can use REST methodologies for invoking and handling CRUD operations over HTTP. My goal is to manage CRUD transactions for about 5 entities via [POST, GET, PUT, DELETE]. In total, I'd have to write 20 different prototypes even if I can reuse some boilerplate in a helper function.

I'd like to reduce that amount of code with generic types. Here is what I was thinking:

```
abstract class RestResource
{
    int id;
    static String name = "";
    RestResource({required this.id});
    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => throw UnimplementedError();
    factory RestResource.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => throw UnimplementedError();
}

class ActualResource extends ResourceRest
{
    final String additional;
    static String name = "resource";
    ActualResource({required this.additional, required int id}) : super(id: id);

    @override
    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() { 
        // return serialized 
    };

    @override
    factory RestResource.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) { 
        // create object from json 
    };
}

// Example for GET request for a resource with an id ex: api/resource/1234
Future<Resource> fetch<Resource extends RestResource>(int id) async {
    Uri url = Uri.http('http://www.someurl.com/api/', Resource.name + id.toString());
    http.Response res = await _httpClient.get(url);
    validateHTTPResponse(res);
    return Resource.fromJson(convert.jsonDecode(res.body));
}

// This is how I'd want to call it
int id = 1234;
ActualResource r = await fetch<ActualResource>(id);
```

My problem.
`Resource` is a generic Type even if it extends the definition of `RestResource`. Calling the factory method `Resource.fromJson` triggers the following Intellisense errors.

on Resource.name

```
The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type 'Type'.
Try importing the library that defines 'name', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'name'.
```

on Resource.fromJson

```
The method 'fromJson' isn't defined for the type 'Type'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fromJson'
```

I'd like to start a discussion on how developers could do something like this because it would save a considerable amount of time and energy.

Answer (score 1):

After further research, I discovered that my approach is not currently possible with Dart w/Flutter since dart:mirrors is only available on VM. Here is the solution. I hope that it will help other flutter developers reduce the amount of boilerplate when writing REST Api clients. Thank you to Günter Zöchbauer for this answer: [Dart Client-Side Type Generic REST Api Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68840841/dart-client-side-type-generic-rest-api-calls)

```
abstract class RestSerializable {
  RestSerializable.fromJson(); 
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();
}

class ResourceA implements RestSerializable { // whatever you need + fromJson() + toJson() }

class ResourceB implements RestSerializable { // whatever you need + fromJson() + toJson() }

RestReource fromJson<RestReource extends RestSerializable>({required dynamic json}) {
  return jsonFactories[RestReource]!(json);
}

final jsonFactories = <Type, Function> {
  ResourceA : (Map<String, dynamic> json) => ResourceA.fromJson(json),
  ResourceB : (Map<String, dynamic> json) => ResourceB.fromJson(json),
};

final unencodedPathFactories = <Type, String> {
  ResourceA : "/api/resourceA/",
  ResourceB : "/api/resourceB/",
};

RestReource fromJson<RestReource extends RestSerializable>({required dynamic json}) {
  return jsonFactories[RestReource]!(json);
}

String unencodedPath<RestResource extends RestSerializable>() {
  return unencodedPathFactories[RestResource]!;
}

class RestApiClient {
  static const String AUTHORITY = "localhost:port";
  final http.Client _httpClient;

  // This is just one example.... You can add for POST, PUT, DELETE
  // GET Details
  Future<Resource> fetch<Resource extends RestSerializable>(int id) async {
    Uri url = Uri.http(AUTHORITY, unencodedPath<Resource>() + id.toString());
    http.Response res = await _httpClient.get(url);
    this.validateHTTPResponse(res, unencodedPath<Resource>());
    return fromJson<Resource>(json: convert.jsonDecode(res.body));
  }
}
```